# Extending a Nested Placeholder in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to @extend a SCSS placeholder with nesting, and have that nesting reflected in the resulting class?

Given a nested placeholder:

```
%my-form-field {
  ...

  &__label {
    ...
  }

  &__feedback {
    ...
  }
}
```

I currently have to do the following:

```
.one-of-many-targets {
  @extend %my-form-field;

  &__label {
    @extend %my-form-field__label;
  }

  &__feedback {
    @extend %my-form-field__feedback;
  }
}
```

But I'd like to be able to simplify this to:

```
.one-of-many-targets {
  @extend %my-form-field;
}
```

... and have it resolve to:

```
.one-of-many-targets { ... }
.one-of-many-targets__label { ... }
.one-of-many-targets__feedback { ... }
```

Is there a different way to write my placeholder and @extends to make the SCSS cleaner, as in the 2nd example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixin instead:

```
@mixin my-form-field() {
  width: 10px;
  &__label {
    width: 20px;
  }

  &__feedback {
     width: 30px;
  }
}

.one-of-many-targets {
  @include my-form-field();
}
```

will generate:

```
.one-of-many-targets {
  width: 10px;
}
.one-of-many-targets__label {
  width: 20px;
}
.one-of-many-targets__feedback {
  width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try use `selector.append()`

See: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2808#issuecomment-574413393

Also see more info why parent selector didn't work as you expect in extend-only selectors: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2262#issuecomment-291645428